# Android R & layout error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am a beginner Android app developer. I created an XML layout called "splash" and I have changed `setContentView(R.layout.activi­ty_main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.splash­);` but got an error. I tried to do everything all over again but I got the same error in the `R`. When I did a "quick fix" a new error appears. It was caused by `activity_main` and `splash`.

When I started all over again, I just changed the background in `activity_main` but but I got the same error although I haven't modified anything in MainActivity.java.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.**activity_main**);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.**menu**.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: check your imports to ensure that you are **NOT** importing `android.R` sometimes eclipse will sneak that in there, and it is rarely desirable and will generally cause compile errors related to your own R ids.

Comment: Do you have a "splash.xml" layout file in your res/layout folder?

Comment: Try cleaning your project, and executing it. If an error comes up and refers to missing R.java, Then it check the layout file for syntax errors or missing attributes.

Comment: I have removed the quickfix tag, as it is not for eclipse quickfix rather the Financial Information eXchange protocol.  Please be careful when using tags

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when importing R because the Android OS provides one with system defaults etc.
Have a look in your imports to make sure you're getting the R from your package.
You might also see issues if your layout doesn't compile.

Comment: yeap, i've already created "splaysh.xml" before i tried modifying anything. Also what i have above is this :
package com.example.thebasiscs;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

Also ive cleaned it up many times and i couldn't run it because of the errors. and im not sure how to check if im getting the R from my package. However, before this error it has compiled correctly the splash layout. Then, suddenly, everything turns into an error because of the R , the "R.layout.main_activity" and the "R.layout.activity_main"

Comment: The "import android.R; " bit means that you're using the system R. You'll want com.example.the basics.R I think